# How to begin using HTML DOM

Tags: dom, wordpress

I have trouble understanding how some things are related.

For a Wordpress plugin, I would like to use HTML DOM on content from wp_remote_open to find a string.

In order to use DOM, does it have to be enabled by my webhost? or do I include a DOM parsing script with the plugin?

I was thinking that if it needs to be enabled by the webhosting company, I would rather use a regular expression to find the string because then it would be compatible for everyone's installation.

Answer (score 1):

DOM has nothing to do with your hosting provider or infrastructure. It is merely a model representing your HTML document. Most modern browsers support DOM. See more at the [XML DOM introduction](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_intro.asp)

Comment: Ok, thanks.  It says manipulating DOM can be used in any language, and I would like to use it with php.  Does the webhost need to have some things enabled to allow me to write php to use DOM? Because there are some installation requirements listed here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/dom.requirements.php